# Javascript Prime Numbers - Need Clarification on How 2 is Prime.

Tags: javascript

I've searched for this answer and I couldn't find an explanation. I know this answer might be dumb but I just need some clarification on how the following function works. 
If I enter in isPrime(2) I understand that it returns true because it's prime, but what I don't understand is how. Since isPrime(2) will be 2 % 2 === 0 shouldn't it return false?

```html
function isPrime(value) {
    for(var i = 2; i < value; i++) {
        if(value % i === 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return value > 1;
}
```

Comment: hint: for `value = 2`, `i < value` is always false

Comment: ... and value > 1 is true

Comment: The loop is never executed because the loop condition is not fulfilled. The condition is checked *before* the body executed. Hence `return value > 1;` is executed.

Comment: omg thanks so much for the explanation!!! Sorry, I just started learning.

Comment: @samiHam may I ask, how does your function check for prime number?

Answer (score 2):

When you pass this '2' to your function isPrime(2), this doesn't go through for loop because condition in loop is not fulfilled, it goes through 'return value > 1', which is a conditional operator '>' returns true if condition is true otherwise false. So when you pass 2, it returns 'true' because (2 > 1).

Check this [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Greater_than_operator)

Cheers